# Trying to create an image changing div in css

Tags: jquery, css, photo

I'm trying to create an image changing box in a website.

Made some attempts but none came to any fruition.

[image: Example]

Is an example of what I'm looking to do basically.

I'd like the user to be able to click the arrows to change the image.

Really struck out looking for answers on this one.

I'd prefer to stick with css and html, but if I need to I am open to JavaScript (jquery) and PHP as well

Any thoughts on where to start or anyone who has a method would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Need your code to show *what you have tried*, and we can show you where you went wrong...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created a nice demo that uses jQuery take a look and download the example if you want.

http://jsbin.com/ubowoq/3/edit

Comment: This was definitely a real question. And I'd like to thank roXon for answering it. And in further reading on jquery, the script you linked I stumbled across a couple of different options that do basically the same thing. Thank you very much your demo was awesome.

Answer (score 1):

For this functionality you must use javascript. You will not be able to do this with css and html alone.

I recommend using existing jQuery plugins. Why recreate the wheel?

Here is an example of a jQuery cycle plugin that would meet your needs:

http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle2/demo/prevnext.php

Good luck, have fun, and let us know if you have any problems.

Comment: In doing some further research I've discovered that it is possible to do this without javascript.

@recreating the wheel: Some people have scripts disabled on their browser, and while the current support for ccs3 is low, hopefully in the future it will be something that is considered standard. In which case, you will be able to have native support without scripts for things like this

http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2012/04/25/pure-css3-cycling-slideshow/

There is the CSS3 only version